# Telerik winforms how get selected row > ID column value > In hierarchy > Templates[0]

Tags: winforms, telerik, hierarchy, radgrid

I want to get Telerik winforms selected row > ID column value > First Column > In hierarchy > Templates[0] < This is my child template.

For the master template we can act like this :

```
Selected_ID_Main_Person = int.Parse(Grid_PhoneBook.CurrentRow.Cells["ID"].Value.ToString());
```

But what about child template?
I tried this with no help :

```
 this.Grid_PhoneBook.MasterTemplate.Templates[0].CurrentColumn???????????
```

**Edit :**
This code returns selected column index :

```
this.Grid_PhoneBook.MasterTemplate.Templates[0].CurrentColumn.Index
```

But how can i get it's value? (Also i need first column of selected row's value)

Comment: With a loop we can find active row and after that goal column. But what is the command?

Comment: There's a CurrentCell property in radgrid

Comment: How can i figure out what is the first column from CurrentCell? I stucked on it badly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Grid_PhoneBook.CurrentRow** property will always return the current row in RadGridView, no matter in which template it resides, so you can rely on this property only.

To check if the current row is from master or child template, you can refer to its **ViewTemplate** property.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code, though I didn't test it but it should do the job:

```
 GridViewHierarchyRowInfo hierarchyRow = this.Grid_PhoneBook.CurrentRow as GridViewHierarchyRowInfo;

 foreach (GridViewRowInfo row in hierarchyRow.ChildRows)
 {
    if(row.IsCurrent)
    {
        string firstColumnValue = row.Cells[0].Value; 
        break;
    }
 }
```